# View not found exception when runnig an ASP.NET MVC site from a network share

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm getting a View not found exception when my ASP.NET MVC site is configured with is home directory pointing to a network share in IIS.

The weird thing is that this error appears intermittently, sometimes the view loads fine and others the same view fails.

I've tested this in IIS 6 and 7, both have the same problem.

I also have other ASP.NET WebForms sites on the same web server configured in the same fashion (files from a  network share) and they have no problems, which makes me I think this is a bug in the MVC framework, specifically in the view look up process.

Have anyone else experienced something similar and/or know a solution?

Thanks,
Rafael.

Comment: Does everything work well if the home dir is local?

Comment: Yes, there are no problems then.

Answer (score 0):

The connection to shared drives is not persistent, meaning that the connections are "refreshed" in a sense when accessed. Since web forms compiles the entire site at run time the pages are accessed once during the compilation process (in a pre-compiled app you down even actually need the aspx pages).

However in MVC only the code in the controllers is compiled, leaving the views to be accessed by request at run time. If the view is not immediately available the MVC engine will throw an exception.

So if you hit MVC app the first time it will throw an error saying it can't find the view, but on subsequent requests immediately after it should find the view without issue. Until the connection state to the shared folder is closed, when you will get the error again.